# The Effort to Keep Credit Card Information Away from My Shared Server while using ASP.Net Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, security, pci-compliance

Focusing on clients who can not afford PCI compliant servers I intend to limit credit card information to a form entry that posts to the gateway via SSL. I do not store CC info on my clients shared server. My question is about the ASP.NET web form that uses server controls and if form information is in any way run through my clients shared and potentially unsecure server just by using form elements with runat=server. In this form I am using plain html input elements to collect the CC#, CVV# and expiration date but the submit element uses runat=server as I have logic in the code behind that limits the visibility of the button if a condition is not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form on the shared server accepts card details then that server & network must be PCI compliant, the fact that the details are not stored doesn't matter. Given that its a shared server achieving compliance will be virtually impossible.

The best way to keep card data away from the shared server is to have its page host an IFrame for a page thats hosted on a dedicated, compliant server.

Comment: Is this true even if there are no postbacks? If a plain html form posts the data via ssl to a secure server is the shared server not bypassed? I am very interested to know.

Comment: The server that hosts the form is in scope of pci so needs to be compliant, reason being that if it were breached/exploited it would be possible for an attacker (or data center employee) to modify the pages & harvest card data. pci tries to prevent this by mandating hardened networks/intrusion detection/change monitoring/physical security/code reviews (also applies to plain html) yada yada yada.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth. Mine eyes are open now. I believe I will have to host an IFrame on a dedicated compliant server for each of my clients.

Answer (score 1):

If you never have any postbacks that should work, but if you do have any controls that support postbacks, the cc info will possibly be included (depends upon viewstate).

It sounds like you're going to have access to the cc info, as otherwise it doesn't make sense to make the button visible or not...

Comment: Actually the button visibility depends upon the purchase amount field being filled. The cc field is validated client-side with js. The accepted.aspx page is hosted on my gateway server which posts back sanitized order input to the order db. I am determined to find a solution for small businesses to use affordable servers. Thanks for the input and I will look into the viewstate problems.

Comment: Ah, that should do it then. If the cc info never hits your server, you're PROBABLY not in scope (payment processors can set some of the requirements, which makes it impossible to say for sure).

Comment: Thanks @jmoreno. It is a royal pain to skirt PCI and still be secure. I think the little guys deserve it though. What do you think about hosting IFrames on a PCI compliant server and serving them to my checkout page?

Comment: Not that I'm recommending their services, just as evidence that the method is acceptable: see Evalons developer guide https://www.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchant/download/developerGuide.pdf.